# Black (purplish) screen after boot

Tags: boot, nvidia

I need help with ubuntu.
I installed ubuntu 16.04.2 - fresh installation, completely vanilla.
Here are the steps I took:
 1. install ubuntu vanilla
 2. update ubuntu (via the update from gui)
 3. reboot
 4. check again for updates (none)
 5. install nvidia driver (via gui -> system settings -> software -> additional drivers -> proprietary driver 367)
 6. reboot
 7. blank screen (cannot reach login, though splash is shown)
color is kind of black with purple.
Please help
(I can disable the nvidia driver and use ubuntu without it, but it takes the whole point of using it)
Here is what I already know:
 8. I do not have secure boot at all (my bios is older then that)
 9. I can't tty (ctrl+alt+F#)
 10. I had manjaro (Arch linux variant) installed before on this system and the card worked there, so its not HW issue
 11. When I had ubuntu 14.04, it was working great (assuming I had 14.04 and not 14.04.5) - so I'm guessing that something is broken with either kernel or the script which installs the driver to the kernel
 12. please ... help !!!

Comment: It, maybe, don't an aswer to your question, but you can try it with Ubunutu 16.10?

Comment: 16.04.2 uses kernel 4.8. Is the Nvidia 367 the lastest, and kernel 4.8 compatible? Check at the nvidia web site and see if there's something newer for your specific card.

Comment: I tried 16.10 before. It gave the same results as 16.04.2 and 16.04.1 and 16.04 (every once in a while I go back to see if Ubuntu fixed this).  
The driver used to work when I was on 14.04 (not 14.04.5 which breaks it).  
I suspect a bug in Ubuntu, but I have no way to debug it since the system is completely broken.

Comment: Here are the things I tried (after each installation I installed the Nvidia driver from the additional drivers settings):  
1.  Install ubuntu 16.10 - same results  
2. Install Ubuntu 14.04.5 - same results  
3. Install ubuntu 14.04.0 and update - same results  
4. Install ubuntu 14.04.0 with no update - same results  
5. Reinstall Manjaro Linux (Arch based) with proprietary drivers - works!!  
   Manjaro is using driver 375.58 (I think its latest from Nvidia)  
So, no ubuntu since I can't get the nvidia driver to work, and I'm positive its not a driver issue